# What is Promise$2 in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, api, promise, dropbox

I'm using dropbox API to get files from a folder of photos that I own, and what I eventually want to do is get a temp link to each file. This is my code - I'm also using React if that helps:

```
componentDidMount() {
    dbx.filesListFolder({ path: '/my-photos' })
    .then(res => res.entries.map(file => file.path_display))
    .then(res => {
        let photoArray = res.map(path => dbx.filesGetTemporaryLink({ path: path }));
        console.log(photoArray);
    });
}
```

And this is what I see on my dev console.
[image]

I received the temp in the _result object but it seems like I'm not supposed to get access to it.

Could anyone Please tell me what Promise$2 means and how I can solve this problem?

Comment: its a promise type. you will have to some how get to each one.

Comment: like `Promise.all`

Comment: It's simply the name of the prototype of the object that the API is returning. The name suggests that it's some kind of promise.

Comment: Thank you all! `Promise.all` on the second `map` solved the problem!

Answer (score 2):

`Promise$2` is the name of your `Promise` constructor from a promise library that was bundled together with other modules, and renamed by the transpiler in the course of that to avoid collisions with other `Promise` variables (most notably, the global one).